# How do you read STDOUT into variables in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, stdout

I read the bandwidth usage by `ifstat`, which prints the download and upload into `STDOUT` every second.

```
ifstat -i wlp7s0
      wlp7s0      
 KB/s in  KB/s out
 1390.13     81.20
 1039.14     74.05
 1810.63    102.08
  865.60    183.15
 1272.91    274.19
 1174.00    400.04
```

How can I run `ifstat` in a bash script and read the values into variables for an `if statement` to run a command if the values are smaller than an amount?

For example,

```
if [ $in -lt 100 ] && [ $out -lt 100 ]
then
   echo Network is slow.
else
   echo Network is fast.
fi
```

How can I read the output of `ifstat` into `$in` and `$out` variables to check the `if statement` every second?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the network speeds are not integers, we need to supplement with other tools such as awk to process the numbers.  Try:

```
ifstat -ni wlp7s0 | awk 'NR>2{if ($1+0<100 && $2+0<100) print "Network is slow."; else print "Network is fast."}'
```

Or, for those who like their commands spread over multiple lines:

```
ifstat -ni wlp7s0 | awk '
    NR>2{
        if ($1+0<100 && $2+0<100)
            print "Network is slow."
        else
            print "Network is fast."
    }'
```

#### How it works

The `-n` option is added to `ifstat` to suppress the periodic repeat of the header lines.

`NR>2{...}` tells awk to process the commands in curly braces only if the line number, `NR`, is greater than two.  This has the effect of skipping over the header lines.

`if ($1+0<100 && $2+0<100)` tests whether both the first field, `$`, and the second field, `$2`, are less than 100.  If they are, then `print "Network is slow."` is executed. If not, then `print "Network is fast."` is executed.

Answer (score 13):

John1024 is right about floating point numbers, but we can just truncate the numbers. With plain bash:

```bsh
n=0
LC_NUMERIC=C  ifstat -i $interface  \
| while read -r in out; do
  ((++n < 2)) && continue # skip the header
  if (( ${in%.*} < 100 && ${out%.*} < 100 )); then
    echo Network is slow.
  else
    echo Network is fast.
  fi
done
```

Comment: This works too.

Comment: This only works in locales that use a period as the decimal separator (which seems to be OP's case). Setting `LC_NUMERIC=C` would take care of other locales.